MPI_Scatterv is not working when called from different functions
So I am writing a program that dynamically allocates an array of values to different processes. However, different processes call different functions. So at the moment process 0 calls the function send_dynamic_allocation and the function recv_dynamic_allocation is called in the parallel region where the other processes are. So first the sendcounts and displacements is calculated and MPI_Send is used to communicate to the non-zero processes from process 0.
The following code is implemented in send_dynamic_allocation executed by process 0:
 void send_dynamic_allocation(int *legal_moves, int nr_legal_moves){
    FILE *fp;
    int my_rank, comm_sz;
    int debug = 69;

    int *recv_moves;
    int recv_movev_sz;
    int send_moves_sz;

    int *sendcounts;
    int *displacements;


    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD , &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD , &comm_sz);

    write_debug_file(nr_legal_moves,"Number of legal moves --> ", fp);

    int remainder = nr_legal_moves%(comm_sz-1); /*number of moves that remain after division is equal*/

    write_debug_file(remainder,"remainder --> ", fp);

    sendcounts = (int *)malloc(comm_sz*sizeof(int));
    displacements = (int *)malloc(comm_sz*sizeof(int));
            
    if(remainder == 0){

        send_moves_sz = nr_legal_moves/(comm_sz-1); /*Divide by 3 so that proc 0 isn't loaded with work*/
        sendcounts[0] = 0;

        for(int i=1; i<comm_sz; i++){
            sendcounts[i] = send_moves_sz;
        }

        displacements[0] = 0; /*nothing is sent to proc 0*/
        displacements[1] = 0;
        displacements[2] = send_moves_sz;
        displacements[3] = 2*send_moves_sz;

        print_array_debug_file(sendcounts, comm_sz, "Sendcount when divisable by 3 --> ", fp);
        print_array_debug_file(displacements, comm_sz, "displacement when divisable by 3 --> ", fp);

    }else{

        send_moves_sz = (nr_legal_moves-remainder)/(comm_sz-1);
        sendcounts[0] = remainder; /*Process 0 will receive the remainder so that it isn't overloades by work*/

        for(int j=1; j<comm_sz; j++){
            sendcounts[j] = send_moves_sz;
        }

        displacements[0] = 0;
        displacements[1] = remainder;
        displacements[2] = remainder+send_moves_sz;
        displacements[3] = remainder+(2*send_moves_sz);

        print_array_debug_file(sendcounts, comm_sz, "Senccounts when not divisable by 3 --> ", fp);
        print_array_debug_file(displacements, comm_sz, "displacement when not divisable by 3 --> ", fp);

    }

    /*Send sendcounts to !0 processes*/
    for(int q=1; q<comm_sz; q++)
    {
        MPI_Send( sendcounts , comm_sz , MPI_INT , q , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        print_array_debug_file(sendcounts, comm_sz, "Senccounts being sent by process 0 --> ", fp);
    }

    /*Send displacements to !0 processes*/
    for(int r=1; r<comm_sz; r++)
    {
        MPI_Send( displacements , comm_sz , MPI_INT , r , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        print_array_debug_file(displacements, comm_sz, "displacements being sent by process 0 --> ", fp);
    }

    recv_moves = (int *)malloc(sendcounts[0]*sizeof(int));

    int proc0_sendcount = sendcounts[1];
    recv_moves = (int *)malloc(proc0_sendcount*sizeof(int));
    MPI_Scatterv( legal_moves , sendcounts , displacements , MPI_INT , &recv_moves , proc0_sendcount , MPI_INT , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    
    
    free(sendcounts);
    free(displacements);
    free(recv_moves);

}

The following code is implemented in recv_dynamic_allocation, executed in the non-zero process parallel region. (if(my_rank != 0){/execute the following/})
void recv_dynamic_allocation(){
    FILE *fp;
    int my_rank, comm_sz;
    int debug=0;

    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD , &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD , &comm_sz);

    int recv_moves;
    int *sendbuf=0;
    int *sendcounts;
    int *displacements;

    sendcounts = (int *)malloc(comm_sz*sizeof(int));
    displacements = (int *)malloc(comm_sz*sizeof(int));

    /*Receive sendcounts from process 0*/
    MPI_Recv( sendcounts , comm_sz , MPI_INT , 0 , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    print_array_debug_file(sendcounts, comm_sz, "Senccounts being received by process !0 --> ", fp);
    
    /*Receive displacements from process 0*/
    MPI_Recv( displacements , comm_sz , MPI_INT , 0 , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    print_array_debug_file(displacements, comm_sz, "displacements being received by process !0 --> ", fp);

    
    
    int recv_count = sendcounts[my_rank];
    recv_moves = (int *)malloc(recv_count*sizeof(int));

    MPI_Scatterv( &sendbuf , 0 , displacements , MPI_INT , &recv_moves , recv_count , MPI_INT , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    
    free(recv_moves);

}

I know the order of communication is correct because I made sure by just using MPI_Send and MPI_Recv. It causes a crash, but due to the nature of the project, I am unable to view the exact error message.
I tried different displacements, I've tried different recv_counts. I have tried a lot, and still don't know what is the problem. I know its not the order of communication between different processes, because is tested it with MPI_send and I'm pretty sure MPI_Scatterv is blocking, so it should finish and not be interfered with by other communication.
Here is another example of how it works from chatGpt:
Here's an example of using MPI_Scatterv to scatter an array [1, 2, 8, 7, 9, 6, 4, 7, 5, 6, 2, 6] to four processes such that:
The first process receives 2 element
The second process receives 4 elements
The third process receives 5 elements
The fourth process receives 1 element
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int root = 0;
    int *sendbuf = NULL;
    int *recvbuf = NULL;
    int *sendcounts = NULL;
    int *displs = NULL;

    // Initialize the array on the root process
    if (rank == root) {
        sendbuf = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sendbuf[i] = i + 1; // Example data: 1, 2, 3, 4
        }

        // Prepare the sendcounts and displs arrays for scatterv
        sendcounts = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        displs = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            // Example: [2, 4, 5, 1]
            sendcounts[i] = i + 1;
            displs[i] = offset;
            offset += sendcounts[i];
        }
    }

    // Allocate memory for the receive buffer in all processes
    recvbuf = (int *)malloc((rank + 1) * sizeof(int));

    // Scatter the data from the root process to all other processes
    MPI_Scatterv(sendbuf, sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT, recvbuf, rank + 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Print the received data in each process
    printf("Process %d received: ", rank);
    for (int i = 0; i < rank + 1; i++) {
        printf("%d ", recvbuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Cleanup
    if (sendbuf != NULL) free(sendbuf);
    if (recvbuf != NULL) free(recvbuf);
    if (sendcounts != NULL) free(sendcounts);
    if (displs != NULL) free(displs);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}


In the non root code recv_moves has type int, it should be int*.
